# str TypeError, yes it's basic but hear me out

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know, this is probably a very simple problem, but no matter how many times I go through this, this isn't making any sense. I made a very simple class that is meant for controlling an Arduino-based car. I set it up so that the serialOut function will return a string with the necessary formatting to send over serial. However, whenever I use it, I keep getting this error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
>     car.serialOut()
> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
> ```

this is the code for the class:

```
# Drive Communication System
import serial

def output(speed,steer,orientation):
        return ('%02d' % speed) + ('%02d' % steer) + (orientation)

class DriveTrain:

    def __init__(self,serial,cruise_speed = 60, turn_sensitivity = 1):
        self.serialOut = '0045s'
        self._cruise = cruise_speed
        self._trim = turn_sensitivity
        self._speed = 0
        self._steer = 0
        self._orientation = 's'

    def Drive(self,speed, steer = 0, orientation = 's'):
        self._steer = steer + 45
        self._speed = speed
        self._orientation = orientation

    def stop(self):
        self._steer = 45
        self._speed = 0
        self._orientation = 's'

    def status(self):
        return (self._speed,self._steer - 45,self._orientation)

    def serialOut(self):
        return output(self._speed,self._steer,self._orientation)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ser = serial.Serial('COM3',38400)
    car = DriveTrain(ser)
    car.Drive(60)
    #car.Drive(60)
```

Originally, I had the operations currently in the output function in the actual serialOut class function, but the same things happened. I also attached a picture that shows how I went through checking each operation, and yet for some reason it still won't work. I'm obviously missing something simple, but for the life of me, I just can't figure out what it is...

[image: Testing the code]

Comment: You're defining serialOut as a a string. Why are you trying to execute it as if it were a function? If you want it to be a function, define it as one in the class. Otherwise, don't put the parentheses after serialOut if you are trying to get that value.

Comment: Remove the `self.serialOut = '0045s'` line

Comment: Eric is right... You're trying to have two properties on the inside of your class with the name `serialOut`... when you make a new instance of the class the function is overwritten....

Comment: Please avoid pictures of code. It is much more likely for people to be able to help if they can quickly reproduce your problem.

Comment: ...I am an idiot. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `__init__`, you have:

```
self.serialOut = '0045s'
```

This has the effect of overriding the `serialOut` method (since it has been assigned to each class instance).  Just remove the assignment (or use a different name).

Comment: Yup that's it. I'm an idiot, I completely forgot that line was even there. Thanks for the assist.